# How to display gamemode in Minecraft multiplayer server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

Is there any possible ways to display every players game mode on screen such as setdisplay function/command? This would be used so that server OP's did not cheat to get resources that they want.

Comment: This isn't a bad question, but keep in mind if you suspect someone or unsure if they might cheat they probably shouldn't be OPPed

Comment: there is a situation, most of my friends is kinda new to this game, i can remove that person from being OP but i just don't want to be mean as a friend. i understand, sometimes its okay to use cheat but it becomes wrong when it being overused for personal purpose. it becomes contradict with the purpose of playing survival mode :/

Answer (score 3):

Create a dummy variable: `/scoreboard objectives add gamemode dummy`

In a repeating command block, set their score to 1 if they're in creative: `/scoreboard players set @a[gamemode=creative] gamemode 1` (You'll need to `/forceload` the chunk the repeating command block is in.)

And add it to the sidebar: `/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar gamemode`

This will show in the sidebar whether someone has entered creative mode, even if they swap back to survival mode afterwards. To reset it, do `/scoreboard players set PLAYERNAME gamemode 0`, replacing PLAYERNAME with the name of the player.

Comment: It's obviously not foolproof, as the OP can just set their own scoreboard variable to 0, but if an OP is determined to cheat you can't really stop it without plugins.

Comment: I'll add up to this a bit: you can create a team by `/team add <teamName>` and add a color to it with `/team modify <teamName> color <teamColor>`. Now you can join the team: `/team join <teamName> <playerName>`. Now you can display the scoreboard only for members of that team, so the 'cheaters' won't suspect anything. Setting the scoreboard for team members only can be done with `/scoreboard setdisplay sidebar.team.<teamColor> <yourObjective>`. Hope this makes sense and I also hope the syntax isn't wrong, I haven't done commands in some of the newer versions yet.

Comment: im looking forward to do as what you suggest ! i'll update soon :D

Comment: " (You'll need to /forceload the chunk the repeating command block is in.)" actually, since spawn chunks are always loaded you can simply use them

Comment: @Topcode Yes. They are forceloaded.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way of doing it with a plugin. Make sure you are running Spigot and download the PAPI plugin. Then move it to your plugins folder and restart/start your server.

Once the plugin is loaded, type `/papi ecloud download Player`. Then reload using `/papi reload` and use the placeholder `%player_gamemode%` anywhere you want.

Comment: do you mean PlaceholderAPI? sounds cool, i'll give it a try soon !